# No injection source found for a parameter of type @FormDataParam

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to upload files using a java rest service and I think I have a problem with parameters that service method has.

I have this stacktrace:

```
12:56:24,030 SEVERE [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors] (MSC service thread 1-6) Following issues have been detected: 
WARNING: No injection source found for a parameter of type public java.lang.String org.vozCiudadana.restService.RestUploadService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.text.ParseException at index 0.

12:56:24,031 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./vozCiudadanaWAR: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./vozCiudadanaWAR: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public java.lang.String org.vozCiudadana.restService.RestUploadService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.text.ParseException at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class org.vozCiudadana.restService.RestUploadService, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@39b949c8]}, definitionMethod=public java.lang.String org.vozCiudadana.restService.RestUploadService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.text.ParseException, parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, source=file, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.String}, nameBindings=[]}']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:502)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:327)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:220)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:125)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:509)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:88)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more

12:56:24,044 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "vozCiudadanaWAR.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./vozCiudadanaWAR" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./vozCiudadanaWAR: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public java.lang.String org.vozCiudadana.restService.RestUploadService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.text.ParseException at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class org.vozCiudadana.restService.RestUploadService, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@39b949c8]}, definitionMethod=public java.lang.String org.vozCiudadana.restService.RestUploadService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.text.ParseException, parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, source=file, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.String}, nameBindings=[]}']"}}
12:56:24,087 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "vozCiudadanaWAR.war" (runtime-name : "vozCiudadanaWAR.war")
12:56:24,089 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./vozCiudadanaWAR: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./vozCiudadanaWAR: Failed to start service

12:56:24,165 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
12:56:24,166 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
12:56:24,166 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" started (with errors) in 14871ms - Started 271 of 330 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 92 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
12:56:24,331 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment vozCiudadanaWAR.war
12:56:24,357 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) JBAS011403: Stopping Persistence Unit Service 'vozCiudadanaWAR.war#OGMvozCiudadana'
12:56:24,359 INFO  [org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) OGM001202: Closing connection to MongoDB
12:56:24,445 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment vozCiudadanaWAR.war (runtime-name: vozCiudadanaWAR.war) in 132ms
12:56:24,723 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "vozCiudadanaWAR.war" (runtime-name: "vozCiudadanaWAR.war")
12:56:24,725 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".component."org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./vozCiudadanaWAR (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."vozCiudadanaWAR.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./vozCiudadanaWAR
```

Also I have this pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

and this in the web.xml:

```
  <init-param>  
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>  
       <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;         
    org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>  
</init-param>
```

and a service class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;  
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("files")
public class RestUploadService {

    private static final String FOLDER_PATH = "C:\\my_files\\";

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public String uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fis, 
                         @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition f                
                         ) throws ParseException {

        OutputStream outpuStream = null;
        String fileName = f.getFileName();
        System.out.println("File Name: " + f.getFileName());
        String filePath = FOLDER_PATH + fileName;

        try {
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
            while ((read = fis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                 outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            outpuStream.flush();
            outpuStream.close();
        } catch(IOException iox){
           iox.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(outpuStream != null){
                try{outpuStream.close();} catch(Exception ex){}
            }
        }
        return "File Upload Successfully !!";
    }
}
```

any help please?

**EDIT:**

Until that 17 version I have always called my service this way:
sample: http://192.168.1.250:8080/vozCiudadanaWAR/rest/vozCiudadana/hola_mundo
where

1. http://192.168.1.250:8080/vozCiudadanaWAR from ip:port/warProyect
2. servlet mapping --> rest
3. vozCiudadana from my class path definition   @Path("/vozCiudadana/"))
4. /method_name --> hola_mundo

Now, how do i have to call my service and methods?

Comment: Can you add on your question how are you calling this service?

Comment: I don't know, everything looks good. Only thing I would change is to make the multipart maven dependency the same version as the other two Jersey dependencies. I don't see that being a problem, but it something you definitely want to change.

Comment: i have upgrade both dependencies (org.glassfish.jersey.containers and org.glassfish.jersey.core) from 2.16 to 2.22.1 abd now i can deploy it...good..
i will continue and we will see if everything is ok.